# Pivot/Transpose in SQL Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

I didn't know if my problem is related to Pivoting or Transposing so that's why I wrote both in the title.

Below is my query (using it in an Oracle APEX Report)

```
SELECT QUESTION_ID,
       RESPONDENT,
       ANSWER
FROM   SURVEY
```

Here is the result :

```
Question_ID Respondent  Answer
1           A           test1 
2           A           test2
3           A           test3
1           B           test4
2           B           test5
3           B           test6
```

The result I want is this :

```
                   Question
Respondant   1        2       3
A          test1    test2   test3
B          test4    test5   test6
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: PIVOT is a bit more general than transposing, but yes, transposing is one of the applications. Because PIVOT is an aggregate operation, you must use an aggregate function (like MIN or MAX) even when it doesn't seem necessary, as the MIN(answer) in the solution I offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from table_name
pivot ( min(answer) for question_id in (1 as q1, 2 as q2, 3 as q3));
```

Comment: Perhaps. The number of questions must be known beforehand though, it can't be variable. And the `question_id` must be known too (such as, it should run from 1 to 90, or perhaps from 3001 to 3090, etc. - the id's must be known when you write the query). However, with 90 questions, why would you want a format with 90 columns?

Comment: The ids are known, from 1 to 90. I used a third party application to insert data in my table and this is how it inserted it. and my customer needs a refinement on the data. otherwise I would never design like this. thanks for the help. giving it a go now, it if works will mark as the correct answer,